# What is the difference between .zshrc and .zshrc.local and when is .zshrc.local sourced?

Tags: zsh

I was following this tutorial https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Development_environment_with_nix-shell

And it says to put some code in `.zshrc.local`. I never heard about this file and can't find any documentation about it.

What is the difference between .zshrc and .zshrc.local and when is the latter sourced?

Comment: There is no builtin meaning in `.zshrc.local` from the viewpoint of **zsh** itself. Of course you can give your files any name you want, as long as you remember how to use them, and some zsh frameworks may have their own additional files ..... The section INVOCATION in _man zshall_ tells you the relevant file names for zsh.

Comment: Thanks @user1934428, I don't know from where they get that .local, I expect some standards on docs :(((

Comment: You could start a new shell with `zsh -i -x` and the output will show you at what point it is processed.

Comment: Oh, nice trick!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file `.zshrc.local` is specfic to Grml's Zsh config: https://github.com/grml/grml-etc-core/blob/master/etc/zsh/zshrc#L14

The page you linked to is from [an unofficial NixOS users' wiki](https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Main_Page). Whoever wrote that page just happened to use Grml and apparently didn't realize that `.zshrc.local` is non-standard. Grml is also referred to [in a couple of other pages on that wiki](https://nixos.wiki/index.php?search=grml&go=Go).

Comment: The page I posted don't seems to be related to grml, I really don't know why they instruct fro non-standard things, but nixos is fully non-standard so no surprises

Comment: The page you linked to is from an [unofficial NixOS users' wiki](https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Main_Page). Whoever wrote that page just happened to use Grml and apparently didn't realize that `.zshrc.local` is non-standard. Grml is also referred to [in a couple of other pages on that wiki](https://nixos.wiki/index.php?search=grml&go=Go).

Comment: @geckos Anyway… Do you think you could accept my answer? It answered your question. :)

Comment: Accepted  can you please add that "The page you linked is from an unofficial NixOS users wiki" comment to the answer, this is important I didn't realize that until your comment

Comment: Sure. I added it now.